# Time out error sql when joined table is empty

Tags: jquery, sql, join, timeout

I am stuck with the following WITH part. When there are no results when the startdate and enddate condition is not met the query takes a very long time and eventually returns a time out error. When there are records matching the period the result is normal with no errors.

```
    ILY as (
        select 
        A.[EANcode] as 'EAN',
        FL.[ContractId] as 'FacContractId',
        SUM(case when FL.[Tp] = 'Dal' AND FL.[LijnType] = 'Statement' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Dal_Statement',
        SUM(case when FL.[Tp] = 'Dal' AND FL.[Lt] = 'Account' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Dal_Account',
        SUM(case when FL.[Tp] = 'Dal' AND FL.[Lt] = 'InvoicedAccount' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Dal_InvoicedAccount',
        SUM(case when FL.[Tp] = 'Piek' AND FL.[Lt] = 'Statement' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Piek_Statement',
        SUM(case when FL.[Tp] = 'Piek' AND FL.[Lt] = 'Account' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Piek_Account',
        SUM(case when FL.[Tp] = 'Piek' AND FL.[Lt] = 'InvoicedAccount' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Piek_InvoicedAccount',
        SUM(case when FL.[Tp] = 'Enkel' AND FL.[Lt] = 'Statement' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Enkel_Statement',
        SUM(case when FL.[Tp] = 'Enkel' AND FL.[Lt] = 'Account' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Enkel_Account',
        SUM(case when FL.[Tp] = 'Enkel' AND FL.[Lt] = 'InvoicedAccount' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Enkel_InvoicedAccount',
        SUM(case when FL.[Tp] = 'TL Dal' AND FL.[Lt] = 'Statement' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'TLDal_Statement',
        SUM(case when FL.[Tp] = 'TL Dal' AND FL.[Lt] = 'Account' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'TLDal_Account',
        SUM(case when FL.[Tp] = 'TL Dal' AND FL.[Lt] = 'InvoicedAccount' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'TLDal_InvoicedAccount',
        SUM(case when FL.[Tp] = 'TL Piek' AND FL.[Lt] = 'Statement' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'TLPiek_Statement',
        SUM(case when FL.[Tp] = 'TL Piek' AND FL.[Lt] = 'Account' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'TLPiek_Account',
        SUM(case when FL.[Tp] = 'TL Piek' AND FL.[Lt] = 'InvoicedAccount' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'TLPiek_InvoicedAccount'
    
        from {FactuurLijn} FL
        inner join {Factuur} FAC on FAC.[Id] = FL.[FactuurId]
        inner join {FactuurContract} FC on FC.[FactuurId] = FAC.[Id]
        inner join {Aansluiting} A on A.[Id] = FC.[AansluitingId]
        inner join {PriceComponent} PC on PC.[Id] = FL.[PrijscomponentId]
        where A.[EANcode] in (select getContracts.[EANCode] from getContracts)
        and FC.[ContractId] in (select getContracts.[ContractId] from getContracts where getContracts.[ContractNummer]  <> '')
        and (FL.[StartDate] >= @StartDate and FL.[EndDate] <=@EndDate)
        and PC.[PriceType] = 'VP'
        and PC.[PriceComp] = 'Levering'
        and FAC.[Show] = 1
        and FL.[ContractId] <> 0
        group by A.[EANcode], FL.[ContractId], FL.[Tp], FL.[Lt]
    )

select .....
```

I have changed the joins to left joins and also changed the sum clause to ISNULL(SUM(...),0)
But this had no effect. (I have changed some column names to improve readability for this post).

Answer (score 0):

If this is a edge case, you can use `IF` to handle it like:

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM {FactuurLijn}
    WHERE (FL.[StartDate] >= @StartDate and FL.[EndDate] <=@EndDate)
)
```

if true, then execute your normal query, which is fast, else return empty result set or message.

Alternatively, you can try to filter the rows in advanced in another CTE or table. Something like this:

```
ILY_Filtered AS
(
    SELECT [FactuurId]
    FROM {FactuurLijn}
    WHERE (FL.[StartDate] >= @StartDate and FL.[EndDate] <=@EndDate)
        and FL.[ContractId] <> 0
)
```

Then in your query you will have:

```
from ILY_Filtered FLF
INNER JOIN {FactuurLijn} FL
   ON ELF.[FactuurId] = FL.[FactuurId]
```

but I prefer to store this results in tables (variable or temporary or something else your RDMS offers).

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solution. Problem is if I check only on the dates I will miss out on the other filters which might also cause empty results (currently I only know of empty results when the dates do not match) and I have to also check if the eancodes and contractIds are in the getcontracts tables I created before. So this means if I need to check first if there are results I will have to run a bigger query. Will this not be overkill? first running the query to check if there are results then do the query again (but with the sum)..

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the query to:

```
InvoicesCheck as (
SELECT 
  FL.[FactuurId],
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (select {FactuurLijn}.[Id]
        from {FactuurLijn} FL
            inner join {Factuur} FAC on FAC.[Id] = FL.[FactuurId]
            inner join {FactuurContract} FC on FC.[FactuurId] = FAC.[Id]
            inner join {Aansluiting} A on A.[Id] = FC.[AansluitingId]
            inner join {PrijsComponent} PC on PC.[Id] = FL.[PrijscomponentId]
            where A.[EANcode] in (select getContracts.[EANCode] from getContracts)
            and FC.[ContractId] in (select getContracts.[ContractId] from getContracts)
            and (FL.[StartDatumFactuurLijnDetail] >= @StartDate and FL.[EindDatumFactuurLijnDetail] <=@EndDate)
            and PC.[PrijsType] = 'VP'
            and PC.[PrijsComponentType] = 'Levering'
            and FAC.[Tonen] = 1)
       then 'TRUE' 
       else 'FALSE'
  end as 'Found'  
FROM {FactuurLijn}
),
InvoicesLastYear as (
    select
    A.[EANcode] as 'EAN',
    FL.[ContractId] as 'FacContractId',
    case when InvoicesCheck.[Found] = 'TRUE'
    then    
    SUM(case when FL.[Tariefperiode] = 'Dal' AND FL.[LijnType] = 'Statement' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Dal_Statement',
    SUM(case when FL.[Tariefperiode] = 'Dal' AND FL.[LijnType] = 'Account' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Dal_Account',
    SUM(case when FL.[Tariefperiode] = 'Dal' AND FL.[LijnType] = 'InvoicedAccount' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Dal_InvoicedAccount',
    SUM(case when FL.[Tariefperiode] = 'Piek' AND FL.[LijnType] = 'Statement' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Piek_Statement',
    SUM(case when FL.[Tariefperiode] = 'Piek' AND FL.[LijnType] = 'Account' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Piek_Account',
    SUM(case when FL.[Tariefperiode] = 'Piek' AND FL.[LijnType] = 'InvoicedAccount' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Piek_InvoicedAccount',
    SUM(case when FL.[Tariefperiode] = 'Enkel' AND FL.[LijnType] = 'Statement' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Enkel_Statement',
    SUM(case when FL.[Tariefperiode] = 'Enkel' AND FL.[LijnType] = 'Account' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Enkel_Account',
    SUM(case when FL.[Tariefperiode] = 'Enkel' AND FL.[LijnType] = 'InvoicedAccount' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'Enkel_InvoicedAccount',
    SUM(case when FL.[Tariefperiode] = 'TL Dal' AND FL.[LijnType] = 'Statement' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'TLDal_Statement',
    SUM(case when FL.[Tariefperiode] = 'TL Dal' AND FL.[LijnType] = 'Account' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'TLDal_Account',
    SUM(case when FL.[Tariefperiode] = 'TL Dal' AND FL.[LijnType] = 'InvoicedAccount' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'TLDal_InvoicedAccount',
    SUM(case when FL.[Tariefperiode] = 'TL Piek' AND FL.[LijnType] = 'Statement' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'TLPiek_Statement',
    SUM(case when FL.[Tariefperiode] = 'TL Piek' AND FL.[LijnType] = 'Account' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'TLPiek_Account',
    SUM(case when FL.[Tariefperiode] = 'TL Piek' AND FL.[LijnType] = 'InvoicedAccount' then FL.[Hoeveelheid] else 0 end) as 'TLPiek_InvoicedAccount'
    else 
        0 as 'Dal_Statement',
        0 as 'Dal_Account',
        0 as 'Dal_InvoicedAccount',
        0 as 'Piek_Statement',
        0 as 'Piek_Account',
        0 as 'Piek_InvoicedAccount',
        0 as 'Enkel_Statement',
        0 as 'Enkel_Account',
        0 as 'Enkel_InvoicedAccount',
        0 as 'TLDal_Statement',
        0 as 'TLDal_Account',
        0 as 'TLDal_InvoicedAccount',
        0 as 'TLPiek_Statement',
        0 as 'TLPiek_Account',
        0 as 'TLPiek_InvoicedAccount'
        end
    from {FactuurLijn} FL
    inner join {Factuur} FAC on FAC.[Id] = FL.[FactuurId]
    inner join {FactuurContract} FC on FC.[FactuurId] = FAC.[Id]
    inner join {Aansluiting} A on A.[Id] = FC.[AansluitingId]
    inner join {PrijsComponent} PC on PC.[Id] = FL.[PrijscomponentId]
    where A.[EANcode] in (select getContracts.[EANCode] from getContracts)
    and FL.[ContractId] in (select getContracts.[ContractId] from getContracts)
    and (FL.[StartDatumFactuurLijnDetail] >= @StartDate and FL.[EindDatumFactuurLijnDetail] <=@EndDate)
    and PC.[PrijsType] = 'VP'
    and PC.[PrijsComponentType] = 'Levering'
    and FAC.[Tonen] = 1
    group by A.[EANcode], FL.[ContractId]
    )
```

However the message I am getting is incorrect syntax near the word 'as' and 'and'.
Can we do an EXISTS inside a WITH clause?